# Reloading QGIS Plugin?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I`m currently using Plugin Reloader to reload the plugin I am writing. However, every time I have an error and try to reload it, I end up having two icons for the same plugin. Also, external Python modules that are imported to the plugin python module are not reloaded.

```
def initGui(self):
# create action that will start plugin configuration
    #self.opendss = QAction(QIcon(":/plugins/testplug/icon.png"), u"OpenDSS", self.iface.mainWindow())

    dir1=os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    self.icon = QAction(QIcon("%s/icons/net.png" %(dir1)), u"OpenDSS", self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.shape_button = QAction(QIcon("%s/icons/shp.png" %(dir1)), u"From Shapefiles", self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.dss_button = QAction(QIcon("%s/icons/dss.png" %(dir1)), u"From DSS files", self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.run_powerflow_button = QAction(QIcon(":/plugins/testplug/pf.png"), u"Deterministic Analysis", self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.display_help_button = QAction(QIcon("%s/icons/help.png" %(dir1)), u"User Guide", self.iface.mainWindow())



    self.iface.registerMainWindowAction(self.shape_button, "F8" )
    self.iface.registerMainWindowAction(self.dss_button, "F9" )
    self.iface.registerMainWindowAction(self.run_powerflow_button, "F10")
    self.iface.registerMainWindowAction(self.display_help_button, "F1")


    self.shape_button.setWhatsThis(u"From Shapefiles")
    self.dss_button.setWhatsThis(u"From DSS files")
    self.run_powerflow_button.setWhatsThis(u"Deterministic Analysis")
    self.display_help_button.setWhatsThis(u"User Guide")
    #self.settings_button.setWhatsThis(u"OpenDSS")

    self.m = self.toolButton.menu()
    self.sm = self.toolButton_load.menu()
    self.m.addMenu(self.sm) # adds a submenu
    self.sm.setTitle("Load Network") # Menu title
    self.sm.setIcon(QIcon(":/plugins/testplug/net.png")) # Submenu icon


    # SubMenu Actions 
    self.sm.addAction(self.shape_button) 
    self.sm.addAction(self.dss_button)
    # Menu Actions
    self.m.addAction(self.run_powerflow_button) 
    self.m.addAction(self.display_help_button)


    self.toolButton.setDefaultAction(self.icon)
    self.iface.addPluginToMenu("&Test Plugins", self.shape_button)
    self.iface.addPluginToMenu("&Test Plugins", self.dss_button)
    self.iface.addPluginToMenu("&Test Plugins", self.run_powerflow_button)
    self.iface.addPluginToMenu("&Test Plugins", self.display_help_button)


    QObject.connect(self.shape_button, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.shape_network)
    QObject.connect(self.dss_button, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.dss_network)
    QObject.connect(self.run_powerflow_button, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.settings)
    QObject.connect(self.display_help_button, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.help)


    #Pushbuttons
    self.dlg_pflow.pushButton_run.clicked.connect(self.run_settings)
    self.dlg_result.pushButton_plot.clicked.connect(self.run_display)
    self.dlg_result.pushButton_show.clicked.connect(self.run_show)
    self.dlg_pflow.pushButton_translate.clicked.connect(self.translate_dss)
    self.dlg_dssnet.pushButton_save.clicked.connect(self.save_all)


    #LineEdit
    self.dlg_pflow.lineEdit_house.clear()
    self.dlg_pflow.lineEdit_pv.clear()
    self.load_all()
    dir1 = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    self.dlg_pflow.lineEdit_pv.setText("%s\\Engine\PV_profiles.mat" % dir1)
    settings.d['pv_path'] = "%s\\Engine\PV_profiles.mat" % dir1
    self.dlg_pflow.lineEdit_house.setText("%s\\Engine\House_profiles.mat" % dir1)
    settings.d['house_path'] = "%s\\Engine\House_profiles.mat" % dir1 


    #self.dlg_dssnet.lineEdit_master.setText("%s\\13Bus\\IEEE13Nodeckt.dss" % dir1)
    #self.dlg_dssnet.lineEdit_bus.setText("%s\\13Bus\\IEEE13Node_BusXY.csv" %dir1)

    #ToolButtons
    self.dlg_pflow.toolButton_house.clicked.connect(self.select_pvprofile_folder)
    self.dlg_pflow.toolButton_pv.clicked.connect(self.select_houseprofile_folder)
    self.dlg_dssnet.toolButton_master.clicked.connect(self.select_master_folder)
    self.dlg_dssnet.toolButton_bus.clicked.connect(self.select_bus_folder)


    #Helpbuttons
    self.dlg_pflow.help_settings.clicked.connect(self.run_help_settings)
    # self.dlg_pflow.help_thermal.clicked.connect(self.run_help_thermal)
    # self.dlg_pflow.help_voltage.clicked.connect(self.run_help_voltage)
    # self.dlg_pflow.help_pv.clicked.connect(self.run_help_pv)
    # self.dlg_pflow.help_graphs.clicked.connect(self.run_help_graphs)
    # self.dlg_pflow.help_create.clicked.connect(self.run_help_create)

    #Buttonbox
    self.dlg_pvprob.button_box.accepted.connect(self.run_pvprob_ok)
    self.dlg_pvprob.button_box_apply.clicked.connect(self.run_pvprob_apply)
    #self.dlg_dssnet.buttonbox_box_dss.accepted.connect(self.run_dss_network)

    #ComboBox
    self.dlg_pflow.comboBox_pv.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.run_pvprob)

    #Progress Bar 
    self.dlg_pflow.progressBar.setMaximum(100)
    self.dlg_pflow.progressBar.setMinimum(0)

    # remove the toolbar
def unload(self):


    self.iface.removePluginMenu("&Test Plugins",self.shape_button)
    self.iface.removePluginMenu("&Test Plugins",self.dss_button)
    self.iface.removePluginMenu("&Test Plugins",self.run_powerflow_button)
    self.iface.removePluginMenu("&Test Plugins",self.display_help_button)
    self.iface.removePluginMenu("&Test Plugins",self.icon)
    self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(self.shape_button)
    self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(self.dss_button)
    self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(self.run_powerflow_button)
    self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(self.display_help_button)
    self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(self.icon)
    self.iface.unregisterMainWindowAction(self.icon)
    self.iface.unregisterMainWindowAction(self.shape_button)
    self.iface.unregisterMainWindowAction(self.dss_button)
    self.iface.unregisterMainWindowAction(self.run_powerflow_button)       
    self.iface.unregisterMainWindowAction(self.display_help_button)
```

Comment: Looks like you need to _unload_ your plugin menu items and icons as described in the [cookbook](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/plugins.html#mainplugin-py) :)

Comment: But when I use the qgis.utils.unloadPlugin command, the plugin is unloaded. The case above only happens when the plugin crashes(find an error)